# apply CSS to set position for icon inside button

Tags: css, ionic-framework

```
 <div class="button button-icon topPull">
   <div class="button button-icon"><i class="icon ion-android-cart"></i><a class="icon-circle icon-circle-outline">
      <i>{{cart.length || 0}}</i>
      </a><div> </div>
```

Now, I want ion-android-cart to be placed near the bottom of the button and anchor link to be at the right top edge of the icon . How do I apply this CSS here?

By default, these appear at the top left corners one after the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code-snippet:

```
.button {
    position: relative;
}


.button i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

The icon will always stay in the absolute middle of the button.